# How do I know that my Samsung HD503HI hard drive supports AHCI?

Tags: hard-drive, ahci

I have [Samsung HD503HI ATA Device (SATA) hard drive](http://www.hdsentinel.com/storageinfo_details.php?lang=/proc/self/environ&model=SAMSUNG%20HD503HI).

I found that AHCI is giving some performance boost and I want to try it. I would reinstall Windows after so drivers are not problem but can my hard drive support AHCI mode?

I have that option in BIOS but I don’t know can my HDD work with it.

Comment: You can make the [registry edit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/922976) and then modify the BIOS setting without even needing to reinstall Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a SATA hard drive, it inherently supports AHCI. Because AHCI is dependent on the host system’s settings and not the hard drive itself. As explained on Wikipedia; bold emphasis is mine:

> The Advanced Host Controller Interface (AHCI) is a technical standard
>   defined by Intel that **specifies the operation of Serial ATA (SATA)
>   host bus adapters** in a non-implementation-specific manner.

Which basically means that AHCI settings *do not* fall on the hard drive, but rather *the host system itself*. Meaning a BIOS setting needs to be changed.

That said, after [reading this webpage](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-change-sata-hard-disk-mode-from-ide-to-ahci-raid-in-bios-after-installing-windows/) it seems like the following registry items need to be changed in the Windows OS itself so it can happily work with AHCI instead of IDE:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\msahci
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\pciide
```

From what I am reading, those two registry items need to be set to `0` and then you need to edit the BIOS settings to set the motherboard to use AHCI and you should be good to go. You don’t need to reinstall Windows and AHCI should then be enabled on your system.

Comment: you are correct but the performance increase the op is asking about is NCQ, which early sata1 drives did not support, so not all hard drives are compatible will all functions of ahci.

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit, I could not find a manual giving an exact answer, but I did find a Tom's Hardware post indicating that most AHCI incompatable hard drives were SATA I, and your hard drive is SATA II.

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1719926/sata-hdd-ahci-compatible.html

At this point, I would guess that it would work without an issue.  If you have the space, you may want to just try installing windows over the partition you already have setup to avoid losing data.  Good luck!

Comment: +1, you are correct, early hard drives did not support all the functions of ahci, NCQ is one of them, which is the performance increase the op is looking for. You should have the green check for the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

AHCI is not dependent on the drive hardware.  It is implemented between the OS and the host controller (usually on the motherboard).  It simply controls how the operating system sees the drive, and allows more advanced SATA features to be used.  The drive itself doesn't really know which mode it's in.  If the drive doesn't support all of the advanced SATA features that AHCI may be able to use, the host controller will negotiate which commands it can use.

You don't have to reinstall Windows to switch modes if you're running Vista or later, but there are some steps to take before changing the setting in BIOS.  Microsoft article [KB922976](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/922976) tells what you need to do to make the switch.

Most problems people have when switching from IDE to AHCI or vice-versa is that the drivers are disabled or missing.